# JavaScript breakpoints in Razor not working in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I have a asp.net core 2.2 MVC application. 
I added the javascript below to my cshtml .
my web browser is Chrome.
I checked the option in Visual Studio ('Script debugging..') which is enabled.
I don't think I am using bundling 
I am able to see popups for so i know the code is being reached.
Breakpoint is empty red circle, and hover over says:

> The breakpoint will not be currently hit

any suggestions ?

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
   alert("Test"); 
});
```

In earlier versions of VS, i was able to debug js by putting in a seperte static file, but this does not work either - still get the empty red circle.

Comment: This is a jQuery issue, not strictly javascript. At least your sample code is jQuery.

Comment: All major browsers have native debugging tools, Visual Studio script debugging was always troublesome to me.

Comment: Yes, VS was always a pain to get working, and VS 2019 really broke it :-(
I'll switch to chrome debugging https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints